# Pointwise Limit of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

For each integer $n \geq 2$, define the function $f_n : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
xn^2,  & \text{if $0 \leq x\leq 1/n$} \\[2ex]
-n^2(x-2/n), & \text{if}{ ~ 1/n < x\leq 2/n}
\\[3ex] 0, & \text{if}{~ 2/n <x \leq 1 }\end{cases}$$

How would I determine the pointwise limit of the sequence $f_n$?

Answer (score 0):

let $x$ be a fixed point in $[0,1]$.

if $x=0$ then for all integers $n$

$f_n(0)=0$ thus

$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to + \infty}f_n(0)=0}$.

if $x \in (0,1]$  then for all integers $n$

such that $\color{red}{n>\frac{2}{x}}$, we will have

$f_n(x)=0$ since $\frac{2}{n}<x$.

this  gives
$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to +\infty}f_n(x)=0}$.

finally the pointwise limit of the sequence $(f_n)$ in $[0,1]$  is the zero function.

Comment: What about the case where 0<x<2/n? As surely $f_n(x)$ =n when x=1/n, if  i'm not mistaken?

Comment: x is fixed and we use the expression of $f_n(x)$ for enough great $n$ to compute the limit.

Comment: ok? you see now how we do.